# You must either pass handleSubmit() an onSubmit function or pass onSubmit as a prop | Redux Forms

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-form

I want to create a simple form that takes in an email adress and later adds it to our database. I went with React Forms, because it facilitates the whole development process and reduces the amount of time.

However, when I'm trying to POST my form I'm getting this error: `Uncaught Error: You must either pass handleSubmit() an onSubmit function or pass onSubmit as a prop`

Here's my **AddUserForm.js:**

```
import React from 'react'
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form'

const AddUserForm = ({ handleSubmit }) => {
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <div>
        <Field name="email" component="input" type="email" />
      </div>
      <button type="submit">Bjud in</button>
    </form>
  )
}
export default reduxForm({
  form: 'addUser'
})(AddUserForm)
```

Here's my **addUserAction:**

```
import axios from 'axios'
import settings from '../settings'

axios.defaults.baseURL = settings.hostname

export const addUser = email => {
  return dispatch => {
    return axios.post('/invite', { email: email }).then(response => {
      console.log(response)
    })
  }
}
```

And here's my **AddUserContainer.js:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { addUser } from '../../actions/addUserAction'
import AddUserForm from './Views/AddUserForm'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

class AddUserContainer extends Component {
  submit(values) {
    console.log(values)
    this.props.addUser(values)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Bjud in användare</h1>
        <AddUserForm onSubmit={this.submit.bind(this)} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return { user: state.user }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { addUser })(AddUserContainer)
```

I am really grateful for all the answers! Stay awesome!

Answer (score 1):

In your **AddUserForm.js**

Here you have to add `onSubmitHandler` as a prop for taking in the submit function that's suppose to run on form submit. You then have to pass the `onSubmitHandler` to `handleSubmit()`

```
import React from 'react'
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form'

const AddUserForm = ({ handleSubmit, onSubmitHandler }) => {
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmitHandler)}>
      <div>
        <Field name="email" component="input" type="email" />
      </div>
      <button type="submit">Bjud in</button>
    </form>
  )
}
export default reduxForm({
  form: 'addUser'
})(AddUserForm)
```

In your **AddUserContainer.js**
Change `onSubmit={this.submit.bind(this)}` to `onSubmitHandler={this.submit.bind(this)}`

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% this is your problem but I would recommend against trying to bind on the form or whatever. Assuming you're storing the input in the state's user object, then you just want to define a submit method, and call it with `this.state.user`. That method should basically just call your api method.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { addUser } from '../../actions/addUserAction'
import AddUserForm from './Views/AddUserForm'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

class AddUserContainer extends Component {
  submit(values) {
    console.log(values)
    this.props.addUser(values)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Bjud in användare</h1>
        <AddUserForm onSubmit={this.submit(this.state.user)} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return { user: state.user }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { addUser })(AddUserContainer)
```

Comment: Hey mister! Thanks for taking your time to answer my question, although that didn't help me. :(